# News Articles Duplicate Detection

Tags: nlp, duplicates

I want to perform near duplicate identification on crawled web news articles. ( I want to find articles on same news item and delete them) I have tried several generic methods such as simhash, shingles and clustering based approaches. but they did not produce reasonable amount of accuracy. Can anyone suggest a approach to do this?

Comment: How did you measure accuracy? Do you already have a reference set to compare with?